# How to create a list from array in javascript?

Tags: arrays

var arr = [1, [1.1,1.2,1.3], 2, ,3];

How do i create a list using only javascript and DOM :

- 1
- - 1.1
  - 1.2
  - 1.3
- 2
- 3

Thanks!!!

Comment: please show us your current code. i think you should use `document.createElement`

Comment: just a moment!!

Comment: http://collabedit.com/92brb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is it with createElement:

```js
function createList(items, parent){
  var ul = document.createElement('ul');
  parent.appendChild(ul);
  items.forEach(function generateList(item) {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    ul.appendChild(li);
    if(Array.isArray(item)){
      createList(item, li);
    } else {
     li.innerHTML = item;
    }
  });
}

var arr = [1, 2, 3, [3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4], 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
var list = document.getElementById('list');

createList(arr, list);
```

```html
<div id="list">
</div>
```

result:

- 1
- 2
- 3
- - 3.1
  - 3.2
  - 3.3
  - 3.4
- 4
- 5
- 6
- 7
- 8

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it. One of them could be:

```js
function displayArrayAsHtmlList(array, element) {
    var ul = document.createElement('ul');
    var prev;
    for (var item in array) {
        if (Array.isArray(array[item])) {
            displayArrayAsHtmlList(array[item], prev);
        } else {
            var li = document.createElement('li');
            li.innerHTML = array[item];
            prev = li;
        }
        ul.appendChild(li);
    }
    element.appendChild(ul);
}

var arr = [ "1", [ "1.1", "1.2" ] , "2" , "3"];
displayArrayAsHtmlList(arr, document.getElementById("div_list"));
```

```html
<div id="div_list"></div>
```

Result will be:

- 1

  - 1.1
  - 1.2
- 2
- 3